# Removing Leading Zeros within awk file

Tags: bash, awk, printf, leading-zero

I am generating a report using an awk file to pull data and write to another file.
Filename:
         dosreport.awk.
This code prints a material number like this 000000000000787301

```
if (substr($0, 1, 7) == "E2EDP19" && E2EDP19seen == 1)
                {
                    printf " " substr($2, 6);
                    E2EDP19seen=E2EDP19seen +1;
                }
```

The relevant data is
`E2EDP19001                       02002000000000000797578`
I need the leading zeros stripped to just give me 787301.
Again, this is within an awk file, so piping to an awk command will not work.

Typecasting the original printf will give me the expected value. Working code

```
if (substr($0, 1, 7) == "E2EDP19" && E2EDP19seen == 1)
                {
                    if (substr($2, 6)+0 == 0)
                    {
                        printf " " substr($2, 6);
                    }
                    else{
                        printf " " substr($2, 6)+0;
                    }
                    E2EDP19seen=E2EDP19seen +1;
                }
```

Comment: A web search would have immediately given you the answer.

Comment: I did a web search thanks, and that didn't work for my problem. Got any input?

Comment: `echo 000000000000787301 | sed 's/^0*//g'`

Comment: It's not even clear how your data looks like, which field you're trying to manipulate and so on.  Saying _didn't work_ doesn't help.

Comment: What do you mean what field I'm trying to manipulate? The printf is targeting the second parameter of the current record. Its a string of digits. Printf is inside of an if statement to determine what line it is on, depending on a set of qualifiers. But that is irrelevant. All I need is the zeros stripped

Comment: Actually, it _is_ relevant because it's clear from how you are using `printf` that you don't really know how to use it.

Comment: K so I'm very new to unix scripting. I've been asked to modify this report script. 
`E2EDP19001                                                   02002000000000000797578`
That's the line containing the data. This is an SAP iDoc file.

Comment: try reading `man gawk`. It's very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `sub(/^0+/, "", $2)`?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{b="000000000000787301"; sub(/^0+/, "", b); print b;}'
787301
```

or typecast it by adding zero:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{b="000000000000787301"; print b+0;}'
787301
```

**update** A working example based on comments:

```
$ echo 'E2EDP19001 02002000000000000797578' | awk '{$2 = substr($2,6); sub(/^0+/, "", $2); print $2;}'
797578
```

or, preserve `$2`:

```
$ echo 'E2EDP19001 02002000000000000797578' | awk '{a = substr($2,6); sub(/^0+/, "", a); print a;}'
797578
```

**up-update** Based on revised post, here's a working sample, just like I proposed many, many revisions ago:

#### `sub()`

```
$ echo 'E2EDP19001                                                   02002000000000000797578' \
   | awk 'BEGIN {E2EDP19seen = 1 } 
       {if (substr($0, 1, 7) == "E2EDP19" && E2EDP19seen == 1) {
       out = substr($2, 6); sub(/^0+/, "", out); print out } }'
797578
```

#### typecast

```
$ echo 'E2EDP19001                                                   02002000000000000797578' \
  | awk 'BEGIN {E2EDP19seen = 1 } 
      {if (substr($0, 1, 7) == "E2EDP19" && E2EDP19seen == 1) {
      print substr($2, 6) + 0 } }'
797578
```

Comment: I tried something like that with sub and gsub. It makes all of the material numbers "1".

Comment: I'm within an executable .awk file and have already used the begin segment. Unless b can be set equal to the the substr value from my original post, that won't work.

Comment: @GeoffBeglau The answer is right in front of you. `BEGIN` is not part of it. I've shown you two ways to do it.

Comment: `b=substr($2,6); sub(/^0+/, "", b); print b;`
I tried that in place of my printf. It dropped the number completely

Comment: @GeoffBeglau if the result of `substr($2,6)` is `000000000000787301` as per OP, then both options work. Why don't you actually show some data, and specifically, what the output of `substr($2,6)` is?

Comment: substr($2,6) is the 000000000000787301

Comment: @GeoffBeglau, no, it's not. Look at the updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry man but I'm not getting it. 
        if (substr($0, 1, 7) == "E2EDP19" && E2EDP19seen == 1){
      printf " " substr($2, 6);         E2EDP19seen=E2EDP19seen +1;
     }
Where does that fit in my code to output the number without 0s?

Comment: maybe you edit your question to include the input, your relevant code, and expected output? that's the normal way to get help rather than having a conversation.

Comment: The typecast option worked. But I failed to mention that not all material numbers contain only numeric characters. But I can take care of that. Thanks for your help

Comment: @GeoffBeglau don't you think you should state that in your initial question? Shouldn't that be part of the representative initial data? You could have made this _much_, **much** easier from the start. No one can read your mind, which is probably why you received so many down votes.

Comment: Dude its the internet. If there are strict rules, make people read them before I can sign up. It took me 30 seconds to create an account, and 2 minutes to get attacked for not being an expert in asking scripting questions and the general usage of this website. I do appreciate your help, but I don't appreciate the fact that I can't assume you all can read my mind if you all can so readily jump to the conclusion that I'm a high level programmer with knowledge of how this website works. It's a two way street.

but again, thank you.